# How to add a unique function to all the movieclips in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to add a specific function to every movieclip. I've added an event listener but all the movieclips are doing the same thing.
I've noticed that I can't do it with the `i` variable because it's 11 could you help me find another way?

```
  package
{
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageOrientation;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.StageOrientationEvent;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import com.thanksmister.touchlist.renderers.TouchListItemRenderer;
import com.thanksmister.touchlist.events.ListItemEvent;
import com.thanksmister.touchlist.controls.TouchList;

[SWF( width = '480', height = '800', backgroundColor = '#000000', frameRate = '24')]
public class AS3ScrollingList extends MovieClip
{
    private var touchList:TouchList;
    private var textOutput:TextField;
    private var stageOrientation:String = StageOrientation.DEFAULT;

    public function AS3ScrollingList()
    {
        // needed to scale our screen
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        if(stage) 
            init();
        else
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, handleResize);

        // if we have autoOrients set in permissions we add listener
        if(Stage.supportsOrientationChange) {
            stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, handleOrientationChange);
        }

        if(Capabilities.cpuArchitecture == "ARM") {
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleActivate, false, 0, true);
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, handleDeactivate, false, 0, true);
        }

        // add our list and listener
        touchList = new TouchList(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        touchList.addEventListener(ListItemEvent.ITEM_SELECTED, handlelistItemSelected);
        addChild(touchList);

        // Fill our list with item rendreres that extend ITouchListRenderer. 
        for(var i:int = 1; i < 3; i++) {
var item:TouchListItemRenderer = new TouchListItemRenderer();
item.index = i;
item.data = "This is list item " + String(i);
item.itemHeight = 120;
item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotostore);
item.buttonMode = true;
touchList.addListItem(item);
}
//not nested function
function gotostore (e:MouseEvent) {
switch(e.currentTarget.name) {
    case "firstMovieClip":
    trace("buton1");
        //first movieclip clicked
        break;
    case "secondMovieClip":
            trace("buton2");
        //second movieclip clicked
        break;
    //etc...
    }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Handle stage orientation by calling the list resize method.
     * */
    private function handleOrientationChange(e:StageOrientationEvent):void
    {
        switch (e.afterOrientation) { 
            case StageOrientation.DEFAULT: 
            case StageOrientation.UNKNOWN: 
                //touchList.resize(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
                break; 
            case StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT: 
            case StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT: 
                //touchList.resize(stage.stageHeight, stage.stageWidth);
                break; 
        } 
    }

    private function handleResize(e:Event = null):void
    {
        touchList.resize(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
    }

    private function handleActivate(event:Event):void
    {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
    }

    private function handleDeactivate(event:Event):void
    {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }

    /**
     * Handle keyboard events for menu, back, and seach buttons.
     * */
    private function handleKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK) {
            e.preventDefault();
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
        } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.MENU){
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SEARCH){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle list item seleced.
     * */
    private function handlelistItemSelected(e:ListItemEvent):void
    {
        trace("List item selected: " + e.renderer.index);
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `gotostore` function is a nested function which is a really bad design practice, do not use nested functions. You can check which movieclip did the user click with the `e.currentTarget.name`, this will give you the `INSTANCE NAME` of the movieclip which the user "selected".

```
for(var i:int = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    var item:TouchListItemRenderer = new TouchListItemRenderer();
    item.index = i;
    item.data = "This is list item " + String(i);
    item.itemHeight = 120;
    item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotostore);
    item.buttonMode = true;
    touchList.addListItem(item);
}
//not nested function
function gotostore (e:MouseEvent) {
    switch(e.currentTarget.name) {
        case "firstMovieClip":
            //first movieclip clicked
            break;
        case "secondMovieClip":
            //second movieclip clicked
            break;
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: so i have between 50-100 items and each one of them i need it to take me to a specific site. how can i add a specific event listener to every item?

Comment: whit the one i used all of them are doing the same thing. i want every item to do a different thing.

Comment: you can set up different actions in the switch's cases... look at the code.

Comment: ok your a life saver when u don't know all the tricks in flash this site is really helpful hope it works

Comment: Look up a beginner guide/tutorial on how to use the Flash IDE.

Comment: sorry i should have done this from the start i've updated the class.

Comment: Now I see the problem, you have absolutely no idea what is the code doing, where to put, etc.. please, before you start programming, research a bit, learn how to use specific languages.

Comment: ...:) i've realised that i need to work with the handlelistItemSelected function i didn't noticed it until now thx a lot for the hints.have a wonderful day